# More efficient way to convert a nested list to .csv in python

Tags: python, csv

I've a nested list like `Python_List` below and I want to make a `.csv`  like below:

```
    Python_List|->  .csv
    [['2','4'],|     2,4   
     ['6','7'],|     6,7
     ['5','9'],|     5,9
     ['4','7']]|     4,7
```

So far I'm using this code:

```
Python_List=[['2','4'],  ['6','7'], ['5','9'], ['4','7']]
with open('test.csv','w') as f:
    for i in range(0,len(Python_List)):
        f.write('%s,%s\n' %(Python_List[i][0],Python_List[i][1]))
```

Are there any alternatives more efficient?

Comment: A remark on your for-loop: You do not need to loop through indexes. Instead loop over the elements themselves `for l in Python_List:`, then the next line reduces to `f.write('%s,%s\n' % tuple(l))`. Anyway you should use `csv.writer`.

Comment: @Nabla thanks this is a very useful trick feel free to post an answer  is a nice way to do what I want!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using the [writer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer) method of the csv module.

It may not be more efficient but it will be easier to understand.

For Example

```
import csv
with open('test.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    csvwriter.writerows(Python_List)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> i = [['2','4'],  ['6','7'], ['5','9'], ['4','7']]
>>> with open('test.csv','w') as f:
...    writer = csv.writer(f)
...    writer.writerows(i)
... 
>>> quit()
$ cat test.csv
2,4
6,7
5,9
4,7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can csv module and its [`writer`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer) method, like this

```
pyList = [['2','4'],  ['6','7'], ['5','9'], ['4','7']]
import csv
with open('Output.txt', 'wb') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    map(csvwriter.writerow, pyList)
```